# Why do queryset[0] and queryset.first() return different records?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I discovered today that I can access elements in a queryset by referencing them with an index, i.e. `queryset[n]`. However, immediately after I discovered that `queryset[0]` does not return the same record as `queryset.first()`. Why is this, and is one of those more "correct"? (I know that `.first()` is faster, but other than that)

Python 3.7.4
django 1.11.20

Comment: `.first()` orders by primary key if you did *not* define a specific order. Furthermore `.first()` is not *per se* faster. In fact, often it will be slower. Depending on whether the queryset is cached already, it can even result in *less* queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a small semantical difference between `qs[0]` and `qs.first()`. If you did *not* specify an order in the queryset yourself, then Django will order the queryset itself by primary key before fetching the first element.

Furthermore `.first()` will return `None` if the queryset is *empty*. Whereas `qs[0]` will raise an `IndexError`.

The claim that `.first()` is faster however is *not* `True`. In fact if you use `qs[n]`, then Django will, behind the curtains fetch the record by slicing with `qs[n:n+1]`, hence it will, given the database backend supports this, make a query with `LIMIT 1 OFFSET n`, and thus fetch one record, just like `.first()` will do. If the queryset is already retrieved, it will furthermore make no extra queries *at all*, since the data is already cached.

You can see the implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/db/models/query.py#L563-L570):

> ```
>     def first(self):
>         """
>         Returns the first object of a query, returns None if no match is found.
>         """
>         objects = list((self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk'))[:1])
>         if objects:
>             return objects[0]
>         return None
> ```

As you can see, if the queryset is already ordered (`self.ordered` is `True`, then we take `self[:1]`, check if there is a record, and if so return it. If not we return `None`.

The code for retrieving an item at a specific index is more cryptic. It essentially will set the limits from `k` to `k+1`, materialize the item, and return the first item, as we can see in the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.11.x/django/db/models/query.py#L260-L289):

> ```
>     def __getitem__(self, k):
>         """
>         Retrieves an item or slice from the set of results.
>         """
>         if not isinstance(k, (slice,) + six.integer_types):
>             raise TypeError
>         assert ((not isinstance(k, slice) and (k >= 0)) or
>                 (isinstance(k, slice) and (k.start is None or k.start >= 0) and
>                  (k.stop is None or k.stop >= 0))), \
>             "Negative indexing is not supported."
>
>         if self._result_cache is not None:
>             return self._result_cache[k]
>
>         if isinstance(k, slice):
>             qs = self._clone()
>             if k.start is not None:
>                 start = int(k.start)
>             else:
>                 start = None
>             if k.stop is not None:
>                 stop = int(k.stop)
>             else:
>                 stop = None
>             qs.query.set_limits(start, stop)
>             return list(qs)[::k.step] if k.step else qs
>
>         qs = self._clone()
>         qs.query.set_limits(k, k + 1)
>         return list(qs)[0]
> ```

Comment: Ah, okay, so `qs.first()` is ordering it by pk before it gets the first item, while qs[0] is not. What "order" is it in, then, before an order is applied to it?

Comment: @SaintWacko: no, only if the queryset was not *ordered* in advance. If you use `MyModel.objects.order_by('some_field')`, then it will *not* order differently. Only if you did not order yourself, then `.first()` will order by the primary key. If you did not specify an order, the database determines one, and that can be *any* order.

Comment: Right, sorry, forgot to specify that I was assuming an unordered queryset. Anyway, that answers my question, but, just out of curiousity, do you have any information on how the database would determine the order? I've retrieved the queryset multiple times and it's always been the same order, just not sure how it's coming by that order.

Comment: @SaintWacko: that often is specified by the underlying characteristics of the indexing mechanism, but it depends from database to database, and furthermore typically a modification (like an insert, remove, or update) will change the order. Some databases often list items from recent to older, but sometimes filtering an an index might change that behavior.