# Why is this output different?

Tags: python, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db.models import Sum, Count, Max, When, Case, Value, IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDay, TruncMonth, TruncYear
import datetime

from .models import Profile, Team

@login_required
def profile(request):
    today = timezone.now()
    user_profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()

    expenses = user_profile.expense_set.annotate(
        field = Case(
            When(created__year=today.year, then=1),
            When(created__month=today.month, then=2),
            When(created__day=today.day, then=3),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField()
        )
    )

    curent_month_expenses = expenses.filter(created__month=today.month)

    expenses_per_day = expenses.annotate(
        day=TruncDay('created')).values('day').annotate(
            expenses=Count('id'), summary=Sum('amount')
        ).values('day', 'expenses', 'summary')

    expenses_per_month = expenses.annotate(
        month=TruncMonth('created')).values('month').annotate(
            expenses=Count('id'), summary=Sum('amount')
        ).values('month', 'expenses', 'summary')

    expenses_per_year = expenses.annotate(
        year=TruncYear('created')).values('year').annotate(
            expenses=Count('id'), summary=Sum('amount')
        ).values('year', 'expenses', 'summary')

    print(expenses_per_year[0])

    print(expenses_per_year.first())

    context = {
        'profile': user_profile,
        'curent_month_expenses': curent_month_expenses,
        'yearly_expenses': expenses_per_year,
        'dayly_expenses': expenses_per_day,
        'monthly_expenses': expenses_per_month,
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context)
```

Why output is different in the print statements?
Outputs:

```
{'year': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'expenses': 6, 'summary': 128400}
{'year': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'expenses': 1, 'summary': 1000}
```

Comment: Given you do not perform an `order_by(..)`, `.first()` orders by primary key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553897/67579

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, `qs.first()` is *not* equivalent to `qs[0]`. The `qs.first()` will, given no ordering exists, order by primary key, as is described in the [documentation on **`.first()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#first):

> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or `None` if there
>   is no matching object. If the `QuerySet` has **no ordering defined**,
>   then the **queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key**.
>   This can **affect aggregation results** as described in [Interaction
>   with default ordering or
>   `order_by()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation-ordering-interaction).

If you order by primary key, it will thus revert the `GROUP BY`. You can solve this by including an `.order_by` yourself:

```
expenses_per_year = expenses.values(
    year=TruncYear('created')
).annotate(
    expenses=Count('id'), summary=Sum('amount')
).order_by('year')
```

You can furthermore already add `year=TruncYear('created')` in the `.values(..)` part, and you do not need to include annotations in the `.values(..)` again. This makes the query more readable.